# Webrtc RTCPeerConnection - set video codec h264

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I would like to establish a video chat connection (webrtc via node signalling server) between the browser and the Hololens 2 device. I already know that Hololens 2 supports only video codec h264, so I want also in the browser side to set the default codec to h264.

How can I set the default video codec to be h264 in the browser?

Comment: I had to use in the js code first the method "getCapabilities" to get the codecs, and then sort them accordingly - prioritizing/putting h264 codecs firs, then use the method "setCodecPreferences", and now it works like a charm. (But for now it works only from Chrome, Firefox seems not to be supported yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hololens only supports H264 and the browser supports VP8 and H264 (which is common and required), H264 will be negotiated without you needing to do anything.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/change-codecs/
demonstrates the APIs for selecting the codecs should it become necessary